# Javascript function accepts both arrays and strings as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    var showRegion = function(key) {
        if (key in regionOptions) {
            var entry       = regionOptions[key];
            var builder     = entry.builder;
            var layoutObj   = entry.layoutObj;
            var viewStarter = entry.viewStarter;

            var view = new builder();
            logger.info('Controller.' + key + ' => CreateAccountLayoutController');
            Controller.layout[layoutObj].show(view);
            view[viewStarter]();
        }
    };
```

What I need is that the parameter should be able to accept an array or a string, and should work either way.

Sample function calls:

```
showRegion('phoneNumberRegion');
showRegion(['phoneNumberRegion', 'keyboardRegion', 'nextRegion']);
```

Comment: [What have  you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Hint: `typeof key == 'string'`

Comment: i thinks its better to use `===` instead of `==` or so i have readed

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco `typeof` always returns a string, and I'm comparing it to a string. `===` is superfluous, since the types are guaranteed to match already.

Comment: @Kolink Thanks for the link. Huge eye-opener.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var showRegion = function(key) {
    if (typeof key === 'string')
         key = [key];
    if (key in regionOptions) {
       ...
```

No need to make a code for each case, just convert key string into an array of one element and the code for arrays will do for both.

Comment: Well except that the original code handled only strings, so now you converted something that works into something that doesn't. But presumably the OP can take your idea and make it work.

Answer (score 19):

This post is old, but here is a pretty good tip:

```
function showRegions(keys) {
  keys = [].concat(keys)
  return keys
}

// short way
const showRegions = key => [].concat(keys)

showRegions(1) // [1]
showRegions([1, 2, 3]) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Same idea as the accepted answer but more elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check for the type of your argument and proceed accordingly, like

```
var showRegion = function(key) {
  if( typeof key === 'object') {
      //its an object
  }
  else {
     //not object
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fact that string.toString() always returns the same string and Array.toString() returns a comma-delimited string in combination with string.split(',') to accept three possible inputs: a string, an array, a comma-delimited string -- and reliably convert to an array (provided that you're not expecting commas to be part of the values themselves, and you don't mind numbers becoming strings).

In the simplest sense:

```
x.toString().split(',');
```

So that

```
'a' -> ['a']
['a','b'] -> ['a','b']
'a,b,c' -> ['a','b','c']
1 -> ['1']
```

Ideally, you may want to tolerate null, undefined, empty-string, empty-array (and still keep a convenient one-liner):

```
( (x || x === 0 ) && ( x.length || x === parseFloat(x) ) ? x.toString().split(',') : []);
```

So that also

```
null|undefined -> []
0 -> ['0']
[] -> []
'' -> []
```

You may want to interpret null/empty/undefined differently, but for consistency, this method converts those to an empty array, so that downstream code does not have to check beyond array-having-elements (or if iterating, no check necessary.)

This may not be terribly performant, if that's a constraint for you.

In your usage:

```
var showRegion = function(key) {
    key = ( (key || key === 0 ) && ( key.length || key === parseFloat(key) ) ? key.toString().split(',') : []);

    /* do work assuming key is an array of strings, or an empty array */
}
```